# Adding SQL Server Compact Edition data source to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce, datasource

I want to add a SQL Server Compact edition in my project in Visual Studio 2013.4, but I don't have the data source in my list:

[image: Change Data Source]

Also, I don't have `System.Data.Sqlce` in my assemblies.

[image: System.Data]

How can I add SQL Server Compact data source to my Visual Studio?

Comment: You know that SQL Compact is deprecated, right? Microsoft recommends using Express or LocalDB instead.

Comment: I don't wanna create a new project base on SQL Server Compact Edition. I have to read data from an `sdf` file that is old.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1: Install the relevant runtime MSI (3.5 SP2 or 4.0)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5783
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709

2: Install the SQL Server Compact Toolbox VS Extension, and browse to the database file, it will also add the connection to Server Explorer (if you really need that)

Comment: Open the Toolbox, go to About, and click Register DDEX, restart VS. In the Toolbox, connect to your database file.

Comment: "SQL Server Compact Toolbox VS Extension" is not available in Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop.  It is not supported.

Comment: @GeoffCoope Use VS Community Edition instead of Express