# How to view .sdf content from within Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sdf

My question is really similar to [how to open *.sdf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375118/how-to-open-sdf-files) but my question is specific how I can view it in Visual Studio

I've added a data connection to my server and as such, I can see the option to browse my database as if I were on SSMS, but within the Server Explorer pane of Visual Studio. This is jolly useful.

I'd like to open an `.sdf` from within the Server Explorer pane of visual studio. I have downloaded the SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox

When I expand my CE database, I see the list of tables, but only an option for refresh and one for properties. No option to edit the content or change the design. Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313744/adding-sql-server-compact-edition-data-source-to-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans Passant's comment put me on right path

I was unable to achieve what I wanted in the Server Explorer Pane, but I could do what I wanted in the SqlLite/Sql Server Compact Toolbox pane. To get this, Tools -> SqlLite/Sql Server Compact Toolbox