# Visual studio: No sql server compact option in data connections

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-ce

It is really unbelievable that I am not able to find such a simple thing, I have searched everywhere.

Actually I want to open sdf file which is a part of my project. I found that it can be opened with sql server management studio, external tools etc. but I want to open it in Visual studio by adding a simple data connection.

Am I asking too much? But Man! I am not able to find this simple thing on internet.
I my add connection window I don't see option for sql server compact data connection.
I already installed compact edition and when I am trying to install it again it is saying that it is already installed.

But for some reason visual studio is not showing up in the list of Data Sources Types.

I found this question, he is facing the same issue and his issue was also not resolved even after applying what was told in the answer

[Adding SQL Server Compact Edition data source to Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313744/adding-sql-server-compact-edition-data-source-to-visual-studio)

Could somebody help to get this simple thing working?

Answer (score 0):

Install the SQL Server Compact Toolbox, it will also install a DDEX provider, that allows you to connect in Server Explorer (for 4.0 only, however)